# What is continuous and what is repeated damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

In regards to casters needing concentration rolls for spells not to fizzle.
Like damage from Wall of fire, Blistering Radiance, Black Tentacles, etc or even normal Grappling?
Is the grappling concentration check separate from continuous damage concentration check or the same one and add half damage to grapple DC?

Comment: Are you referring to the grapple damage for Black Tentacles?

Answer (score 6):

### There's a definition for [*continuous damage*](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101210910/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_continuousdamage&alpha=C); everything else is *repeated damage*

The *Player's Handbook* in the General Guidelines and Glossary describes *continuous damage* as "[d]amage from a single attack that continues to deal damage every round without the need for additional attack rolls" (306). The *Rules Compendium* on Continuous Damage adds a bit more:

> If you’re taking continuous damage, such as from a *Melf’s acid arrow* spell, half the damage is considered to take place while you’re taking your actions. If the last damage dealt was the final damage that the effect could deal, then the damage is over and can’t distract you. Repeated damage isn’t the same as and doesn’t count as continuous damage. (33)

(This largely parrots the description offered in the main body of the *Player's Handbook* under the skill [Concentration](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#concentration) (69-70).)

The spell *Melf's [acid arrow*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#acid-arrow) (*PH* 253) is the go-to example for continuous damage, used as an example of a spell that deals continuous damage in *Complete Arcane*, the *Expanded Psionics Handbook*, the *Player's Handbook*, and, obviously, the *Rules Compendium*.

But, while *Melf's acid arrow* does deal continuous damage because everywhere else says so, the spell *itself* doesn't say that it deals continuous damage. In fact, only a handful things *say* they deal continuous damage: the spells *bothersome babble* (sort of) (*Complete Mage* 97-8), *heartfire* (*Spell Compendium* 112), and the original version of *Tvash-Prull’s bonefiddle* (*Champions of Ruin* 36) (but not the updated *bonefiddle* (*Spell Compendium* 37)); the psionic power *burrowing bonds* (*Complete Psionic* 79-80); and the specific magic weapon *chain of entangling* (*Arms and Equipment Guide* 103) (32,325 gp; 10 lbs.), to name a few. (Other sources likely exist; don't be sad if your favorite's skipped.)

The specificity of the definition of continuous damage means that the list of effects that *can* deal continuous damage *could* be much longer, but because they don't require an attack initially, standing in the effect created by the spell [*wall of fire*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#wall-of-fire) (*PH* 298) shouldn't count, nor should staying in the area of an item on which has been cast the spell *celestial brilliance* (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 94). That's not to say a DM that despises casters *can't* rule either a source of continuous damage *anyway*, but a strict reading of the definition prohibits it.

#### Damage in a typical grapple is not usually continuous damage

A grapple's typically started by making a touch attack that deals *no* damage, so there's no damage present to *be* continuous. Thus a caster usually need only make the already difficult but standard Concentration skill check to, while grappled, [cast a spell](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#grapple-cast-a-spell).

However, a creature possessing the extraordinary ability [improved grab](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#improved-grab) deals damage with the weapon that starts the grapple each round *without* the need for later attack rolls, fitting the continuous damage definition almost perfectly. This DM would have a grappled caster that's also being dealt continuous damage by a natural weapon from a creature with the ability improved grab only make the *higher* of the two Concentration skill checks (*either* for casting in a grapple *or* for the continuous damage): such a caster's *already* in a bad place, after all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46042/discussion-on-answer-by-hey-i-can-chan-what-is-continuous-and-what-is-repeated-d).

Comment: As DM, I rule that the [glossary definition of attack](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101211020/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_attack&alpha=A) is too narrow, and use that of the [*invisibility*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#invisibility) spell: any [action] that targets a foe, or whose area or effect includes a foe.

Comment: @Chemus When applying that definition of *attack* to continuous damage, my concern as a player would be that continuous damage by its own definition still seems to be predicated on making an attack roll (i.e. "without the need for additional attack rolls"). By the way, I think the game makes continuous damage so rare because the rules for continuous damage are so convoluted. Easier to have *wall of fire* on a clock than to deal with the continuous damage rules, for instance.

Comment: That's understandable. The rules change from 2e to 3.x is what made continuous damage convoluted: in 2e, a caster lost a spell if he took *any* amount of damage while casting (initiative had its own bearing on that). 3.x introduced concentration, among other complications.